# Returning View After using an an alert script within the controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

This is a question out of interest in managing JavaScript within the C# code, rather than discussion on whether this is a good design.

I started experimenting with creating an alert from within the controller using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168512/returning-view-after-using-an-an-alert-script-within-the-controller). I understand, it's not usual practice to use JS within a controller.

If I create an alert within a controller, how can I manage the program flow to then return the view. As returning the alert is interfering with the progress to display the view.

The first way suspends the code in DoSomething:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
    // code to get User
    if(User.Role == someRole)
    {
        return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Merchant on Hold');</script>");
     }
    // More code
}

public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
    // Do things
}
```

The second way suspends the code in the Dashboard.

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
    // code to get User
    if(User.Role == someRole)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "AppUser", new { message = 1 });
    }
    // More code
}

public ActionResult Dashboard(int? message)
{
    if(message == 1)
        return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Merchant on Hold');</script>");
    // Do things
}
```

I can't work out how to display the alert with using return Content, as this then prevents the returns within the controller being reached, or if there is a way to direct the alert on close.

I'm looking for  a way to gain control of the program flow after the alert, as it stands, it won't render the view, and the view it's returning to, requires no parameters.

Refreshing the page will cause the alert to re display.

So I'm wondering if this is a viable way at all to display an alert, or if there is a way to manage this within the C#.

Comment: My first question would be - why?

Comment: As soon as you `return` your flow is going to exit your controller and move onto the next step in the pipeline, eventually getting to your view rendering.

Comment: Are you saying you don't want to display and `alert`? Perhaps if you showed where you'd like to return your view it might be clearer what you're trying to do exactly?

Comment: this kind of action would be called via ajax call, not a classic postback..

Comment: If your program flow reaches the `return Content("<script>")` statement, this is will be returned to your front end right away - it will never render the view which I'm assuming you are returning further down in the code.

Comment: And what you want it to do is return the alert statement then continue on to return your view also?

Comment: after alert you can add another line of javascript to call some other action if needed

Comment: set some value in tempdata and return Content then when action is called again check if that TempData key is there if it is there then skip the return Content part and go down to other code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize the TempData if you really want to make your program flow, but something came in my mind which will work without using TempData like this:

```
public ActionResult Dashboard(int? message)
{
    if(message == 1)
        return Content(@"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
                         alert('Merchant on Hold');
                         window.location.href='/AppUser/Dashboard?message=2'
                         </script>
                      ");
    // Do things
}
```

Now when next time the action will be called message would have value 2 and it will skip displaying alert and will move forward to do other things you need.

I hope it give you idea what i am trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand what you're looking for exactly, but is this what you want?

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{ 
     HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("ShowAlert");
     cookie.Value = "1";
     this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
     return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Home", new { message = 1 });
}

public ActionResult Dashboard(int? message)
{
    if (!this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("ShowAlert"))
    {
        return View("Index");
    }

        HttpCookie cookie = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["ShowAlert"];
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        if (message == 1)
            return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Merchant on Hold');</script>");
        else
            return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('indefiend Message');</script>");
    }
}
```