# Return Content with alert in Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to somewhat replicate what I saw in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168512/returning-view-after-using-an-an-alert-script-within-the-controller?rq=1), particularly in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38168767/8102890), but not quite the same.
My intent is, if the zip has no files (it can happen because the folder could be empty) I want to return an alert just so the user is warned that is not possible to obtain the file at the time.
But I'm missing on the redirection point, I don't want the alert to redirect the user to a blank page refering the Action, I want it to stay in the page, also due to some filters.
Is this possible? I couldn't find anything that would stop the redirection from happening.

Here is my the Action Controller code:

```
public ActionResult DownloadZip(List<int> things)
    {
        // Create zip with files

        if (!zip.Any())
        {
            return Content(@"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
                     alert('Message');
                     </script>
                  ");
        }

        // Return zip
    }
```

Here is the call from the view:

```
$("#btnExportToZip").on("click", function (e) {

    var grid = $("#gridThings").data("kendoGrid");
    var items = grid.dataSource.data();
    var lstIds = [];
    $.each(items, function (index, elem) {
        if (elem.Checked) {
            lstIds.push(elem.Id);
        }
    });

    if (lstIds.length > 0) {
        var params = lstIds.join("&listAmostras=")
        var url = '/Search/DownloadZip?listAmostras=' + params;

        window.location.href = url;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do a redirect as you're doing here, it's too late to take it back once you've determined the zip file is empty. Your best bet here is probably to do an AJAX file download. Bear in mind, though, that this will require that the browser supports the HTML5 File API, so IE 9 and under are out.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    async: false,
    xhrFields: {
        responseType: 'blob'
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = 'myfile.pdf';
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }
});
```

Essentially what this does is request the zip file via AJAX. Once the file data has been received, an anchor link is added to the DOM (not visible) and dynamically "clicked" to approximate the behavior of user click a link to a static file. In other words, a download prompt will pop as soon as the AJAX request completes successfully. However, this code only removes the need to redirect. You still need to conditionally pop the download only if the zip file has something in. There's two ways you can accomplish that.

1. In the `success` callback of the AJAX, you would wrap the code there in a conditional that checks that `data.size > 0`. However, that might not actually work. I've never looked at an empty zip file, but it's entirely possible that there's file headers in the binary that would cause the blob to actually have a size greater than zero, even though it's "empty".
2. The better approach is to return an error response in your zip action when the zip file is empty. Off the top of my head, I'm not sure what the most *appropriate* error response code would be, but anything in 400-500 range will work for triggering the appropriate AJAX callback. Then, you just need to add and `error` handler to this AJAX. In that handler, you could then notify the user however you like that there's no download because the zip would be empty.

Comment: Having a Guardin answer me, 'how bout dat'! Now, the problem we face is exactly the browser version of some clients, since many of their professionals are yet using Windows XP computers. So we need to bear in mind the IE is still being used in version 8 or less. I have already done the 2. point, giving a 404 error to notify that were not found files to create a zip. Problably will go back to that solution, as it was the best working one.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, alert is redirect the user to the blank page because in the javascript you have the line `window.location.href = url;` which might be redirect to the same action again which shows the alert.

So try to give the different url to the window.location.href

**for ex:**`window.location.href = '../somecontroller/someaction';`

thanks

Karthik

Comment: The `window.location.href = url` used in there is to make the call to the action and send the necessary Id's to get the related files to include in the zip, so happens before I try to use the alert.